# Delete all directly import/sent kindle books

Tags: kindle

I have plenty of kindle books in my kindle 5, that were directly imported. Either by calibre, or just sending .mobi files to @kindle.com. How do I delete those? Honestly, I would like to erase all my kindle data and redownload all the books that are sync'ed with my amazon account. I tried doing factory reset, but once I connect kindle to my account, all the books are restored as archived items...and deleting them by hand is not an option. In other words I want my kindle device to have only the books that I bought. Any suggestions?

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you sideloading content via calibre? In the future I don't recommend doing this (unless for some reason you don't have access to an Amazon account). When Amazon sends content via Manage Content, it optimizes/streamlines content for the device. If you are just sideloading, the .mobi file will be bloated and take up unnecessary space.

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to go to the [Manage Content](https://www.amazon.com/mn/dcw/myx.html#/home/content/pdocs/dateDsc/) page, select **Your Devices** tab, put a check in the box for the device you want, then in the popup look for the option, **View Device Content**.

Doing that should let you do a mass deletion of items on a device without having to worry about deleting it on the cloud. By the way, for my account, it looks like View Device Content has two listings for each device: one for audio recordings, another for ebooks. You will see the **View Device Content** option only in one of those two listings. This should do it.

Comment: Main disadvantage of this is that all collections in kindle are left. I have ~40 Collections, and all of them are left with 0 entries after deletion...which makes navigation annoying.

Comment: you can delete the collections...